lib/xorg/Xorg →lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so →xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so causes a segmentation fault. Should I report that to Debian team?
Using current debian release,
Linux debian 6.1.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.106-3 (2024-08-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
my session aborted and returned after a while to the login screen when I was using IntelliJ.
A look at /var/log/syslog shows this extract:
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669115+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669256+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Backtrace:
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669593+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x558ca2437f69]
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669987+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x40) [0x7f11e885b050]
2024-09-09T04:46:35.670951+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so (nvidiaUnlock+0x44218c) [0x7f11e7cab06c]
2024-09-09T04:46:35.670989+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671013+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0xb8
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671160+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671177+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: Fatal server error:
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671195+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671213+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671228+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671242+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671267+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671289+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]:  for help.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671307+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671321+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.780532+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.785601+02:00 debian at-spi-bus-launcher[3962]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
2024-09-09T04:46:35.787762+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.834406+02:00 debian gnome-shell[3833]: Invalid temperature from gsd-color: 0 K
2024-09-09T04:46:35.834903+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[706537]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835451+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[706541]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835499+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835680+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[704971]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835873+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[706534]: Exiting due to channel 

Is that something I should report to Debian team as an issue?

more details here:
2024-09-09T04:46:35.520671+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: Warning: Not allowed as a service: com.jetbrains.RoundedCornersManager
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521140+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.jetbrains.JBR$RoundedCornersManager__Holder.<clinit>(JBR.java:514)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521167+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.jetbrains.JBR.isRoundedCornersManagerSupported(JBR.java:524)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521191+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ui.WindowRoundedCornersManager.isAvailable(WindowRoundedCornersManager.java:36)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521210+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.show(AbstractPopup.java:1033)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521228+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.show(AbstractPopup.java:654)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521247+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.showInBestPositionFor(AbstractPopup.java:761)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521270+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.editor.EditorMouseHoverPopupManager.showHintInEditor(EditorMouseHoverPopupManager.java:257)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521289+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.editor.EditorMouseHoverPopupManager.lambda$scheduleProcessing$3(EditorMouseHoverPopupManager.java:194)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521313+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521344+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:229)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521373+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521395+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521414+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread$lambda$1(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:184)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521432+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521455+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:183)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521473+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:836)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521514+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:424)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521603+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:122)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521623+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1162)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521640+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:78)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521658+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:119)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521676+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521693+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521728+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:781)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521746+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:728)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521779+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521798+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521819+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521842+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:750)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521877+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:696)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521896+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$16(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.521961+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithoutImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:117)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522004+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522042+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:73)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522132+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:357)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522153+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522195+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522243+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522288+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522329+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke$lambda$0(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522360+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.lambda$run$0(WriteIntentReadAction.java:24)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522396+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522431+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteIntentReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:910)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522457+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.compute(WriteIntentReadAction.java:55)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522493+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.run(WriteIntentReadAction.java:23)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522554+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522609+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522649+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522708+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522749+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522800+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522837+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:397)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522883+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522926+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.522970+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.523009+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.523053+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.523121+02:00 debian jetbrains-idea.desktop[705535]: #011at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669115+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669256+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Backtrace:
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669593+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x558ca2437f69]
2024-09-09T04:46:35.669987+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x40) [0x7f11e885b050]
2024-09-09T04:46:35.670951+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so (nvidiaUnlock+0x44218c) [0x7f11e7cab06c]
2024-09-09T04:46:35.670989+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671013+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0xb8
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671160+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671177+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: Fatal server error:
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671195+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671213+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671228+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671242+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671267+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671289+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]:  for help.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671307+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.671321+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE)
2024-09-09T04:46:35.780532+02:00 debian /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3612]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.785601+02:00 debian at-spi-bus-launcher[3962]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
2024-09-09T04:46:35.787762+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.834406+02:00 debian gnome-shell[3833]: Invalid temperature from gsd-color: 0 K
2024-09-09T04:46:35.834903+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[706537]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835451+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[706541]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835499+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835680+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[704971]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.835873+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[706534]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836030+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[703293]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836165+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[703857]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836311+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[703056]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836361+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836538+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[703531]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836760+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[703004]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.836911+02:00 debian firefox-esr.desktop[702945]: Exiting due to channel error.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.837319+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.843834+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.844691+02:00 debian systemd[1]: tmp-.mount_jetbraR7wcFm.mount: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.844845+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.845473+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.845613+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.845852+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Consumed 4.527s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.846233+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2024-09-09T04:46:35.846268+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.846403+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Consumed 2.869s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.846550+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.846690+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Consumed 3.165s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.848339+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.848424+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service: Consumed 3.330s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.848580+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.848736+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service: Consumed 2.588s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.848881+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.849026+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: Consumed 4.134s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.849171+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.849316+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: Consumed 4.468s CPU time.
2024-09-09T04:46:35.849454+02:00 debian systemd[3506]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


Yes please, using
reportbug xserver-xorg-video-nvidia

to collect all the relevant information. If the bug is in nvidia_drv.so itself, the Debian maintainers won’t be able to fix it, but they will help you determine whether that is the case, and possibly help forward the issue to the right place.
If you can, it would be useful to provide a backtrace too — see the instructions in this email explaining how to get a backtrace.

Thanks. Submitted as https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1081224
